# UITableViewCell Subclass, Editing Mode problems UILabel resizing when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell subclass (set up in IB). When entering editing mode, the autoresizing masks do their job and resize some UILabels. But when a cell scrolls out of screen, the UILabel seems to resize itself and the text then runs off the screen. Even when ending editing mode, the text doesn't resize back to normal. What can I do to prevent this?

Edit: I should also mentioned, my autoresizing masks for the UILabel are Content Mode Left and Flexible Width. Again, they seem to do their job when first entering editing mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by manually resizing the UILabel in cellForRowAtIndexPath like so:

```
if (tableView.editing) {
    cell.previewLabel.frame = CGRectMake(previewFrame.origin.x,
                                         previewFrame.origin.y,
                                         217,
                                         previewFrame.size.height);
} else {
    cell.previewLabel.frame = CGRectMake(previewFrame.origin.x,
                                         previewFrame.origin.y,
                                         237, 
                                         previewFrame.size.height);
}
```

Still, this is kind of ugly to me, so I'll gladly accept a better solution.